# Myrtle-Muktza Catch 22

Tags: lulav-etrog-arba-minim, muktzeh

My myrtle (*hadas*) broke on Yom Tov Sukkos.

An intact myrtle that is part of a lulav is assur to smell.

The myrtle that broke in the lulav is now muktza because it can't be used.

Now that the myrtle is no longer fit to use for waving, it should be permitted to smell and therefore not muktza.

However, the myrtle only became fit for use on YT (Nolad) and therefore may not be used (Muktza again!).

Do I have this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step "now that the myrtle is no longer fit to use for waving, it should be permitted to smell and therefore not muktza" is inaccurate.

The Hadas remains prohibited to smell the entire day even if it subsequently became invalid because it was set aside for the whole day. (OC 665 and 653)